# How to make a serversocket listen to many ports and make different clients connect to different ports

Tags: java, android, sockets

I had a server client application to transfer files where i need to connect to many clients from one server using sockets. I tried, and got the connections but when compared to a single connection the speed is decreasing when connected to more number of clients so i got an idea to open more ports and connect to different clients from server on multiple ports

This is my code for opening a serversocket

```
 try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
    serverSocket1 = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT1);
    while (true) {
     socket = serverSocket.accept();
     FileThread fileThread = new FileThread(socket);
     fileThread.start();
     socket1 = serverSocket1.accept();
     FileTxThread fileTxThread = new FileTxThread(socket1);
     fileTxThread.start();
    }
```

This is the code for sending files from server

```
DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
   dos.writeInt(f.size());
   for(File file1:f){
       long length = file1.length();
        dos.writeLong(length);
        String name = file1.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(name);
        dos.writeUTF(name);
       FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file1);
       int bs=65508;
       byte[] b= new byte[bs];
       int theByte = 0;
        while((theByte = in.read(b,0,bs)) != -1) dos.write(b,0,theByte);
        in.close();
```

This is my client side code(my client is android device)

```
private class ClntThread extends Thread {
              String dstAddress;
              int dstPort;

              ClntThread(String address, int port) {
               dstAddress = address;
               dstPort = port;
              }

              @Override
              public void run() {
               Socket socket = null;
               try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                int filescount=dis.readInt();
                File[] files=new File[filescount];
                for(int i = 0; i < filescount; i++)
                {
                    files[i] = new File(dirpath + "/" + filesname);
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(files[i]));
                    int bs=65508;
                    byte[] b=new byte[bs];
                    int j=0;
                    while ((j = dis.read(b, 0, bs))!=-1){
                    bos.write(b, 0, j);
                    }
                   bos.flush();
                   bos.close();
                }

                dis.close();
                socket.close();
```

Here how to open different ports on server side and how to connect to server from client as i am mentioning the port number on client side i dont know how client will connect to the unknown port????

I am new to programming and so please give me any suggestions if my approach is wrong

Thank you..

Comment: What your design must have is: 
1. Open range of ports for multiple client.
2. When client tries to connect, have a syncronized thread with a main server at the server end, which will serve feed to client.
3. For many clients, then a spearate process can be deployed for each client-server interaction

Comment: I guess this is an x-y-Problem. Your server won't perform better if you open more sockets or ports. Mind that the port is for connecting with your application. The single connections have their own local ports. So to connect more than 1 client, you have to use a thread for each connection and that's it. Loop for next accept on same port. Still the more clients connected the higher will be the thread count, I/O-Cost ... So if you need to serve more clients, you'll need another machine with another server instance and a load-balancer.

Comment: If you don't want to use so many Threads, you can also have a look at NIO2 and non-blocking I/O.